# Move child folders into a different folder

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am new to UNIX, and I am trying to write a shell script that would move all folders that are older than a day in log archive directory into another folder.

Below is the command I am using for doing so.

```
find /location/logarchive -mtime +1 -type d -exec mv "{}" /Destination/Archives \;
```

This command is moving the parent directory, i.e. `logarchive` into the destination instead of sub folders.

Could you please help me modify this command?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add `-mindepth 1` to your command so as not to include the actual directory you specified initially.

```
find /location/logarchive -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -type d -exec mv "{}" /Destination/Archives \;
```

You might want to also add `-maxdepth 1` if you don't want to recurse into subfolders, which would make sense here, since they're already contained in any upper level folders.